# EC2 instance unable to access its instance role with awscli and ecs-agent

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I've currently writing a Terraform module for EC2 ASGs with ECS. Everything about starting the instances works, including IAM-dependent actions such as KMS-encrypted volumes. However, the ECS agent fails with:

```
Error getting ECS instance credentials from default chain: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain.
```

Unfortunately, most posts I find about this are about the CLI being run without credentials configured, however this should of course use the instance profile.

The posts I do find regarding that are about missing IAM policies for the instance role. However, I do have this trust relationship

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                    "ec2.amazonaws.com",
                    "ecs.amazonaws.com"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

(Added ECS because someone on SO had it in there, I don't think that's right. Also removed some conditions.)

It has these policies attached:

```
AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore        
AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role
```

When I connect via SSH and try to run awscli commands, I get the error

```
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
```

running any command.

But with

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/info
```

I see the correct instance profile ARN and with

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/identity-credentials/ec2/security-credentials/ec2-instance
```

I see temporary credentials. With these in the awscli configuration,

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

returns the correct results. There are no iptables rules or routes blocking access to the metadata service and I've deactivated IMDSv2 token requirement for the time being.

I'm using the latest stable version of ECS-optimized Amazon Linux 2.

What might be the issue here?

Comment: Try adding `ec2.application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com` as a principal in the trust policy

Comment: Same result, unfortunately. I think if it were actually an IAM issue, I a) wouldn't be seeing valid credentials when polling the metadata endpoint with curl and b) I'd be seeing alerts from Cloudtrail where I have the AWS-recommended filters for audit events configured, including AccessDenied etc.

Comment: If you run `aws configure list` on the instance, do you see valid credentials?

Comment: No. Interestingly, though, it does list the region as "type: IMDS" so it seems to be able to connect to the service.